# IntersectionObserver triggers before element enters view

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, intersection-observer

Using Vue, I have the following setup in a component:

```html
<template>
  <article>
    <!-- This content spans several viewport heights: you *have* to scroll to get to the bottom -->
    {{ content }}
  </article>

  <span ref="readMarker" />
</template>
```

```js
// Composition API with <script setup>

const emit = defineEmit<{
  (e: "read", value: number): void
}>()

const readMarker = ref<HTMLSpanElement>()

let observer: IntersectionObserver;
onMounted(() => {
  if (!readMarker.value)
    return

  observer = new IntersectionObserver(
      () => {
        emit("read", 1)
      },
      {
        root: readMarker.value,
      },
  )
  observer.observe(readMarker.value)
})

onDeactivated(() => observer.disconnect())
```

The idea is that when the user scrolls to the bottom of the content (`rootMarker` enters the view), the `read` event is emitted. When the parent receives the event, it loads another component like this and so on (`@read.once="loadMore"`).

However, as soon as I load the page, the event fires immediately, without me having any time to scroll at all. The same event for subsequent instances also fire as soon as the each instance loads.

I also tried using null as the root and creating the observer outside onMounted (with onMounted only containing the `observer.observe()` call), but that changed nothing.

I have clearly misunderstood something about IntersectionObserver, but I'm really confused about this behaviour.

Comment: Aren't you missing the threshold option of the observer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API and maybe do something with the returned elements. I struggled with this API as well.

Comment: All the options are optional, threshold defaults to `0`, which as far as I understand it means the callback is called when even just one pixel of the `rootMarker` is shown. I also tried setting `threshold: 0.7` but I got the same results. The point is that no amount of this element is ever visible before scrolling, so the callback shouldn't trigger, and yet it instantly does.

Comment: Why is the arrow function to intersectionobserver missing the args to the callback? You seem to be observing the root element , shouldn't that be a child element of the root?

Comment: It's missing the arguments because I don't need them. The element i want to observe is `readMarker`. I tried observing it by using the default root instead (the document) but the result was the same.

Comment: 'I load the page, the event fires immediately,'   the callback is called when the intersectionObserver.observe  is initiated and so you should test the position of the target element, usually with 'isIntersecting == true'. You should have the callback taking the entries argument with which you should iterate and test the value isIntersecting.

Comment: I've changed the callback to accept the parameters and am testing for `if (entries[0].isIntersecting)` (I only observe one element), but it still fires immediately and not only when the target enters view; I also tried moving the `span` to within the `article` and changing the root to the latter. How am I supposed to check if the target is intersecting the viewport? Something fundamental about this API still escapes me, I'm very confused.

Comment: Nevermind, I got it: the root has to be the document in order for intersection with the viewport to be considered. If you summarise this as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that if you want to observe scrolling on the viewport itself, the `root` of the IntersectionObserver has to be the `document` itself, whereas in my question I am trying to set `readMarker.value` as root, so the observer would only look in it and, of course, see it as "visible" right away.